# Problem with like it button and public permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-like

I'm a web developer and i'm having problems using the "like it" button
I put the buttom on my site as a counter of votes of a special contest. People can only click the like buttom if they are fan of my Facebook page.
The problem is that people can't vote if they haven't public permissions on his facebook, cause i can't know if they are or not fans of my page.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you rely on information that you are not certain that you can obtain then sadly there is no solution.

Since what you are doing is beyond a simple like button What you may want to try is open a facebook application and request from your users the `user_likes` permission. You can [read more about it here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).  I have photo albums on the "highest privacy setting" - only me.  Yet when I request a list of my photo albums through one of my applications (with the required permissions of course) I get back ALL of my albums.. This might have been a temporary issue that was solved - but in any case - I saw this behavior and I thought it might be relevant to this post :)

Additionally you should look at the [Promotions Guidelines](https://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php) specifically this point :

> You must not use Facebook features or functionality as a promotion’s registration or entry mechanism. For example, the act of liking a Page or checking in to a Place cannot automatically register or enter a promotion participant.

I had some problems with facebook on this issue - you are not allowed to require someone to "like" a page in order to participate in an activity that is not directly connected to that page.
From what I understand you are requireing people to like your page on facebook beofore voting on your site... If this IS the case then facebook might very well start taking action and closing your page/app.